# I need to create a cursor/function/procedure to get this result

Tags: plsql, cursor

I have this table:

```
+----+-------+----------+---------------+
| ID | Name  | Contract | ContractValue |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+
| 1  | Mike  | 001      | 100$          |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+
| 1  | Mike  | 004      | 177$          |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+
| 2  | Diana | 002      | 300$          |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+
| 2  | Diana | 003      | 150$          |
+----+-------+----------+---------------+
```

And with SQL I get this result:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(ContractValue) as ContractValue
FROM table
GROUP BY Name;

+-------+---------------+
| Name  | ContractValue |
+-------+---------------+
| Mike  | 277$          |
+-------+---------------+
| Diana | 450$          |
+-------+---------------+
```

I need to create a cursor/function/procedure that will have the same result as the table above.Of course instead of a table it should be a string like this " Mike managed to obtain 277$". Do anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: You must post what you had tried so far. Asking for codes is really not encouraged here and i hope those who post answers really discourage the person who is posting the query from learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your table actually stores `100$` in `contractvalue`? That means it's a string, which is a really bad data model. If you have to do maths on it you need a numeric column: `contractvalue_usd` storing `100`. Having a string means you're at the mercy of users inputting any old rubbish in whatever format.

Anyway, to address your actual question. There are various different ways of solving this. Here is one,  a function which returns a nested table of formatted strings:

```
create or replace function get_contract_summary 
    return sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll
as
    return_value sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll;
begin
    select name || ' managed to obtain ' 
                || to_char( total_contractvalue ) ||'$'
    bulk collect into return_value
    from (  
        select name, 
               sum(to_number(replace(contractvalue, '$'))) as total_contractvalue
        from contracts
        group by name
        );
    return return_value;
end get_contract_summary;
/
```

Run it like this:

```
SQL> select * from table(get_contract_summary)
  2  /

COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Diana managed to obtain 450$
Mike managed to obtain 277$

SQL>
```